How to ignore keywords in regex before variables?
I trying to create a function which is capable of

putting precision modulator keywords in front of float variables where
there is no such a keyword

So it converts
const float x;

to
lowp const float x;

However I would like to ignore the following scenarios:

When there is already a precision modifier: lowp const float x;
When there is a default precision modulator: precision lowp float;

Based on my previous question link,This is my regex:
  (\bhighp((?:\s+\w+)*)(float|(?:i|b)?vec[2-4]|mat[2-4](?:x[2-4])?)(*SKIP)(?!)|\bfloat\b)

So, I just would like to ignore those cases, when there is a highp|lowp|mediump before float.
I have this regex command:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex/v5/regex.hpp>

using namespace boost;

std::string precisionModulation(std::string& shaderSource) {

    const regex highpFloatRegex2(R"(highp|lowp|mediump((?:\s+\w+)*)(float)(*SKIP)(?!)|(?=\s+(float)))");
    shaderSource = regex_replace(shaderSource, highpFloatRegex2, "lowp");

    return shaderSource;
}

int main() {
    std::string shaderSource = R"(
float foo1;
highp const float foo1;
precision highp float foo2;
    )";

    std::cout << "Original Shader Source:\n" << shaderSource << std::endl;
    std::string modifiedSource = precisionModulation(shaderSource);
    std::cout << "\nModified Shader Source:\n" << modifiedSource << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Unfortunately I got weird results:
Original Shader Source:

float foo1;
highp const float foo1;
const highp float foo1;
precision highp float foo2;


Modified Shader Source:

lowp float foo1;
highp const lowp float foo1;
const highp lowp float foo1;
precision highp lowp float foo2;

I also tried:
\w*(?<!highp)((?:\s+\w+)*)\s+float


I suggest using
\bhighp(?:\s+\w+)*\s+(?:float|[ib]?vec[2-4]|mat[2-4](?:x[2-4])?)(*SKIP)(?!)|\b(?:const\s+)?float\b

See the regex demo.
Details:

\bhighp(?:\s+\w+)*\s+(?:float|[ib]?vec[2-4]|mat[2-4](?:x[2-4])?)(*SKIP)(?!) - matches and skips the following:

\b - word boundary
highp - a word highp
(?:\s+\w+)* - zero or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces followed with one or more word chars
\s+ - one or more whitespaces (in your original pattern, you are missing this pattern and it prevented from matching anything)
(?:float|[ib]?vec[2-4]|mat[2-4](?:x[2-4])?) - float, or ivec/bvec/vec followed with 2, 3 or 4, or mat followed with 2, 3 or 4 and then an optional x followed with 2, 3 or 4


| - or
\b(?:const\s+)?float\b -  a whole word float that is optionally preceded with const and one or more whitespaces.

In your code, it should look like
const regex highpFloatRegex2(R"(\bhighp(?:\s+\w+)*\s+(?:float|[ib]?vec[2-4]|mat[2-4](?:x[2-4])?)(*SKIP)(?!)|\b(?:const\s+)?float\b)");
shaderSource = regex_replace(shaderSource, highpFloatRegex2, "lowp $0");

Note that the $0 in the replacement pattern stands for the whole match value.

Thank you or your answer! It is working fine! Btw, is there any lightweight header only library variant of boost regex lib?

@Fox1942 No, you might be thinking of something as simple as regex.h, but believe me, it is too under-powered.

Yeah, you are right. In case of Boost I can still esxtract the needed headers and build the regex lib only

In case of Boodt regex is the \ the escape character? I can't use it in case of question mark and assigment operator.

@Fox1942 In a regex pattern, a backslash is an escape character of course.

somewhy it is not working:
https://regex101.com/r/7jJEXM/1

No idea what does not work, the third string is a match, yes.

Yeah strange, that words are taken into consideration but not special characters.

If I delete the \b form the beggining it is better, but at =float(1.0f), when there is no white space it is still a match https://regex101.com/r/46o3vf/1

@Fox1942 It must be this regex, use word boundary only where it is expected, and if there can be ZERO or more whitespaces, use \s*, not \s+.

Is there any library, which is not boost , but also supports this regex syntax? :-)

@Fox1942 PCRE or PCRE2.
